# the relation between chaos and fractal basin

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, basins-of-attraction

Does fractal boundary of basin of attraction has something to do with chaos?

I think fractal boundary must lead to chaos, and how about the other way round?

Comment: The boundary is more a foam of (connected components of) pre-images of arbitrary order of the basins of attraction. The chaos is more in the dynamic connecting these open sets, less in its geometrical structure which is highly ordered. So what you are speaking of is the rather orderly trace of one special case of a chaotic dynamical system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you!  What does 'pre-images of arbitrary order' mean?

Comment: I mean the connected components of $f^{-n}(A_k)$, with the $A_k$ the direct basins of attraction.

Answer (score 0):

- Fractal basins imply a chaotic **transient**. To see this, consider any initial condition sufficiently close to the boundary of basins: A small perturbation can make it go to a completely different attractor, hence you clearly have sensitivity to initial conditions in this region.
- Fractal basins do not imply a chaotic **attractor**. For example consider the classical example of three potential wells placed on the corners of a regular triangle: Here the attractors are fixed points, but the basins are fractal. Almost any other standard example for riddled basins also serves as a counterexample.
- Chaos does not imply a fractal basin. Here any system that only has one attractor (which is chaotic) serves as a counter-example, since you only have one basin to begin with. Also, there are chaotic systems that are Hamiltonian and thus the concept of an attractor does not make sense at all.